# python disable error output

Tags: python, xmpp

I created a script that connects via python-xmpp (xmpppy) to chat.euw1.lol.riotgames.com, but I get always an error, even there is none.

Here is the code:

```
jid=xmpp.protocol.JID('my_jid@pvp.net')
cl=xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(),debug=[])
con=cl.connect(server=('chat.euw1.lol.riotgames.com', 5223))
if not con:
    print 'could not connect!'
```

Again: everything works fine, but I still get this nasty error message:

```
An error occurred while looking up _xmpp-client._tcp.chat.euw1.lol.riotgames.com
```

I just wonder how I can prevent xmpppy from outputting it, I have tried several techniques like setting `sys.stdout/stderr` to `os.devnull`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `try/except` structure to handle that problem..

```
try:
    jid=xmpp.protocol.JID('my_jid@pvp.net')
    cl=xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(),debug=[])
    con=cl.connect(server=('chat.euw1.lol.riotgames.com', 5223))
except:
    print 'could not connect!'
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for you answer. I have tried that, but the error message still prints.